# Binding LineSeries with Index

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

The goal is to create a variable number of lines in a WPF chart. I'm trying to create a method in C# that will create a line series and then bind it to a specific index in a     `List<Collection<Point>>`

The xaml that works with a finite number of lines is:

```
<charting:LineSeries Name="LineSeries1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LineGraphDataPoints[0], ElementName=MainControl, Converter={StaticResource JellyConverter}}" IndependentValuePath="X" DependentValuePath="Y" TransitionDuration="0" PolylineStyle="{StaticResource LinePolylineStyle}">
                <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource LineDataPointStyle}" TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Style>
                </charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            </charting:LineSeries>
```

This is the method that I have created to generate new LineSeries at a specific index:

```
private LineSeries createLineSeries(Brush brush, int bindingIdentifier)
    {

        LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
        line.IndependentValuePath = "X";
        line.DependentValuePath = "Y";
        line.TransitionDuration = new TimeSpan(0L);
        line.PolylineStyle = Resources["LinePolylineStyle"] as Style;
        Style style = new Style(typeof(LineDataPoint), Resources["LineDataPointStyle"] as Style);
        Setter backgroundSetter = new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, brush);
        style.Setters.Add(backgroundSetter);
        line.DataPointStyle = style;

        Binding binding = new Binding();
        //binding.Path = new PropertyPath("(0)[(1)]", LineGraphDataPoints, bindingIdentifier);
        //binding.Path = new PropertyPath(LineGraphDataPoints[bindingIdentifier]);
        binding.ElementName = "MainControl";
        binding.Converter = Resources["JellyConverter"] as IValueConverter;
        line.SetBinding(LineSeries.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);


        return line;
    }
```

The issue is that the binding Path for the ItemSourceProperty continues to fail at runtime giving me a XAMLParseException.

If possible, I would like to use `Guid` objects to act as the indexes for my Binding (LineGraphDataPoints would be a `Dictionary<Guid, Collection<Point>>`); however, I'm willing to use `int` indexes if that would make the logic simpler.

Update:
XAMLParseException Details: 
Exception with `binding.Path = new PropertyPath("(0)[(1)]", LineGraphDataPoints, bindingIdentifier);` uncommented.

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'RSI.ChartView.JellyCharting' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '15' and line position '10'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=15
  LinePosition=10
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Windows.Point, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' cannot be used as an accessor parameter for a PropertyPath. An accessor parameter must be DependencyProperty, PropertyInfo, or PropertyDescriptor.
       Source=PresentationFramework
       StackTrace:
            at System.Windows.PropertyPath.ResolvePropertyName(String name, Object item, Type ownerType, Object context, Boolean throwOnError)
            at System.Windows.PropertyPath.ResolvePathParts(ITypeDescriptorContext typeDescriptorContext)
            at RSI.ChartView.JellyCharting.createLineSeries(Brush brush, Int32 bindingIdentifier) in c:\Projects\rsiphase2\RSI\ChartView\JellyCharting.xaml.cs:line 1557
            at RSI.ChartView.JellyCharting..ctor() in c:\Projects\rsiphase2\RSI\ChartView\JellyCharting.xaml.cs:line 237
       InnerException:
```

Exception with `binding.Path = new PropertyPath(LineGraphDataPoints[bindingIdentifier]);` uncommented.

```
  System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'RSI.ChartView.JellyCharting' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '15' and line position '10'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=15
  LinePosition=10
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Object 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Windows.Point, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' cannot be used as an accessor parameter for a PropertyPath. An accessor parameter must be DependencyProperty, PropertyInfo, or PropertyDescriptor.
       Source=PresentationFramework
       StackTrace:
            at System.Windows.PropertyPath.ResolvePropertyName(String name, Object item, Type ownerType, Object context, Boolean throwOnError)
            at System.Windows.PropertyPath.ResolvePathParts(ITypeDescriptorContext typeDescriptorContext)
            at RSI.ChartView.JellyCharting.createLineSeries(Brush brush, Int32 bindingIdentifier) in c:\Projects\rsiphase2\RSI\ChartView\JellyCharting.xaml.cs:line 1558
            at RSI.ChartView.JellyCharting..ctor() in c:\Projects\rsiphase2\RSI\ChartView\JellyCharting.xaml.cs:line 237
       InnerException:
```

Update: 
LineGraphDataPoints is a `List<Collection<Point>>` defined here:

```
public List<Collection<Point>> LineGraphDataPoints
    {
        get { return (List<Collection<Point>>)GetValue(LineGraphDataPointsProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(LineGraphDataPointsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LineGraphDataPointsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LineGraphDataPointsProperty", typeof(List<Collection<Point>>), typeof(JellyCharting), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

I want to bind to the entire `Collection<Point>` stored at a given index in the `List<Collection<Point>>`.

Comment: There's no point in telling us that you get a `XAMLParseException` if you don't tell us what its details are... make sure you look in the inner exceptions as well, because that's normally where your actual `Exception` is found.

Comment: Updated to include the exception details for both of the binding.Path lines.

Comment: As the `Exception` says, you can't use a `Point` as an accessor parameter for a `PropertyPath`.

Comment: I'm trying to use an int. In XAML, I can use `Path=LineGraphDataPoints[0]` where 0 would be the index.  How can I get this same functionality in C#? If an int is a valid accessor parameter in XAML, why isn't it a valid accessor parameter in C#?

Comment: `LineGraphDataPoints[0]` is a `Point`. In plain English, the error says that *you cannot use a `Point` as the `Binding.Path` property value... you can only use a `DependencyProperty`*. Look at the [Creating a bindable Point in C# WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108058/creating-a-bindable-point-in-c-sharp-wpf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for that link! Using that guide, I haven't been able to fix this problem, but it did resolve an issue in another part of my project.  What I'm not understanding with this issue is why the error implies that `LineGraphDataPoints[0]` is a `Point`, but `Point p = LineGraphDataPoints[0]` doesn't compile.

Comment: Dude... Ok, it's not a `Point`, it's a `Collection<Point>`... but that makes no difference here. *You can only bind to a `DependencyProperty` from a `DependencyObject`*. `Point` is a `struct`, *not* a `DependencyProperty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Exception says, you can't use a `Point` as an accessor parameter for a `PropertyPath`. In plain English, that means that you cannot use a `Point` as the `Binding.Path` property value... you can only use a `DependencyProperty`. Look at the [Creating a bindable Point in C# WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108058/creating-a-bindable-point-in-c-sharp-wpf) for more information on this.

`LineGraphDataPoints[0]` is a `Collection<Point>`... but that makes no difference here. You can only bind to a `DependencyProperty` from a `DependencyObject`. A `Point` is a `struct`, *not* a `DependencyProperty`. So even when it's in a `Collection`, it doesn't matter, because you cannot bind to it.

However, that is not necessarily the end of the story. Although you are getting this error, you *could* be doing the wrong thing, so this `Exception` might not matter. I must confess to not knowing anything about these chart tools, but in more normal WPF collection controls, we don't need to manually set the index of each item in the collection.

Instead of that, we simply define a `DataTemplate` to define what each item (or in your case `Point`) should look like. So it *may* be the case, that all you need to do is to define your won `DataTemplate`. Please read the [Data Templating Overview page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN for more information on this. You *may* also need to refer to documentation for your chart controls.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.  I think I'm finally starting to understand how `DependencyProperty` and `DependencyObject` work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind single object of type `Point` to a `ItemsSource` collection:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LineGraphDataPoints[0], ElementName=MainControl ...
```

If you still want to draw single point on chart - you should bind `ItemsSource` to a collection with *only one item/point* or use converter which will "wrap" single element into collection.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify, LineGraphDataPoints is actually a `List<Collection<Point>>`. I'm trying to bind ItemSource to a `Collection<Point>` from the LineGraphDataPoints `List`